# Can you make a global onRendered in iron:router?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I want to run code after each of (or a large set of) my iron:router route templates render. I don't want to have to do

```
Template.foo.rendered = ->
```

for each one.

Answer (score 2):

You could extend the RouteController to a new BaseController with your method, then inherit from the BaseController.

```
BaseController = RouteController.extend({
    onRun: function () {
        // ... do your thing ...
        this.next();
    }
});

HomeController = BaseController.extend({
    template: 'dashboard',
    onBeforeAction: function () {
        // More Stuff
        this.next();
    }
});
```

The onRun (or whatever method you use there) would be run for each of your controllers then.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good solution for existing hooks. There isn't currently an onRendered IR hook.